# dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'liba52-0.7.4' missing

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, package-management, dpkg

I'm trying to run

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and here is the output

```
$ Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  linux-generic-lts-utopic linux-headers-generic-lts-utopic
  linux-image-generic-lts-utopic linux-tools-virtual-lts-vivid
The following packages will be upgraded:
  apparmor apport apport-gtk bash-completion bind9-host
  chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra dnsutils firefox firefox-locale-en
  flashplugin-installer gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 gir1.2-gtk-3.0 libapparmor-perl
  libapparmor1 libbind9-90 libdns100 libexpat1 libexpat1:i386 libgail-3-0
  libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-bin
  libgtk-3-common libisc95 libisccc90 libisccfg90 liblwres90
  libnautilus-extension1a libnss-winbind libpam-winbind libsmbclient
  libsnmp-base libsnmp30 libvdpau1 libwbclient0 linux-firmware linux-libc-dev
  linux-tools-common nautilus-data oneconf oneconf-common openssh-client
  oracle-java8-installer python-oneconf python-samba python3-apport
  python3-oneconf python3-problem-report samba samba-common samba-common-bin
  samba-dsdb-modules samba-libs samba-vfs-modules smbclient ssh-askpass-gnome
  tlp tlp-rdw tzdata winbind xul-ext-ubufox
62 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/81.5 MB of archives.
After this operation, 6,653 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'liba52-0.7.4' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Comment: refer [here](http://lifeonubuntu.com/failed-ubuntu-apt-get-upgrade-corrupts-the-available-file/)

Answer (score 1):

You can just re-install the 'liba52' package:

```
apt-get install --reinstall -y liba52-0.7.4
```

To install this you may have to enable the Universe repository, so consult [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository) if you are not sure how to do this.

Comment: thanks for your answer ,, but it still giving me the same error

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem may caused by an error installation. So you should remove the broken package.
Try this command:

```
sudo apt-get remove some-package --purge
```

and now, you can reinstall `liba52`

```
sudo apt-get install liba52-0.7.4
```